# ActionController StrongParameters syntax embeded parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

UPDATE regarding accessing uploaded_picture:
======>
The culprit was in ImageItem.rb where I had call to upload_picture as private.  Apparently controller call with parms.require.permit is a public call to attr_accessor with before_create on that variable.

With regard to .create! and .update! this param def is working:

def item_image_params

params.require(:items).require(:item).require(:item_images).permit(:item_image_caption, :uploaded_picture)

end 
===== >
Request parameters are exactly -- with regard to structure:
  See below...

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"foo", "commit"=>"new_item",

"items"=>{"item"=>{"field_changed"=>"0", "item_type"=>"lend", "remote_ip"=>"", "item_id"=>"", "participant_id"=>"", "category_id"=>"1", "other_item_category"=>"", "item_description"=>"", "item_condition_id"=>"-2", "item_model"=>"", "item_count"=>"", "notify"=>"0", "comment"=>"", "item_images"=>{"participant_id"=>"", "item_image_id"=>"", "item_image_caption"=>""}},

"contact_preference"=>{"preference_field_changed"=>"1",

"contact_preference_id"=>"20", "item_id"=>"", "user_id"=>"19", "participant_id"=>"899", "use_which_contact_address"=>"0", "contact_by_chat"=>"0", "contact_by_email"=>"0", "contact_by_home_phone"=>"0", "contact_by_Facebook"=>"foo", "contact_by_LinkedIn"=>"foo", "contact_by_Twitter"=>"foo", "contact_by_Instagram"=>"foo", "contact_by_other_social_media"=>"1", "contact_by_other_social_media_access"=>"2"},

"lender_transfer"=>{"transfer_field_changed"=>"0", "lender_transfer_id"=>"foo", "item_id"=>"", "remote_ip"=>"", "participant_id"=>"foo", "user_id"=>"19", "borrower_comes_to_which_address"=>"3", "meetBorrowerAtAgreed"=>"0", "meetBorrowerAtAgreedBorrowerChoice"=>"0", "meetBorrowerAtAgreedMutual"=>"0", "thirdPartyPresenceMutual"=>"1", "borrower_returns_to_which_address"=>"3", "willPickUpPreferredLocation"=>"0", "comment"=>"fgfg"},

"lender_item_condition"=>{"condition_field_changed"=>"0", "lender_item_condition_id"=>"1", "item_id"=>"", "remote_ip"=>"", "participant_id"=>"foo", "user_id"=>"19", "small_fee_amount"=>"12.0", "available_for_purchase_amount"=>"", "trade_item"=>"12", "security_deposit_amount"=>"", "specific_conditions"=>"1221"}}, "id"=>"foo"}

This is not working:

```
def contact_preference_params

params.require(:contact_preference).permit(:item_id, :user_id, :use_which_contact_address,
                 :contact_by_chat, :contact_by_email, :contact_by_home_phone, :contact_by_cell_phone,  
                 :contact_by_alternative_phone, :contact_by_Facebook, :contact_by_Twitter,  :contact_by_Instagram, 
                 :contact_by_LinkedIn,  :contact_by_other_social_media,  :contact_by_other_social_media_access)
```

end

Nor this:

```
def contact_preference_params

params.require(:items).require(:contact_preference).permit(:item_id, :user_id, :use_which_contact_address,
                 :contact_by_chat, :contact_by_email, :contact_by_home_phone, :contact_by_cell_phone,  
                 :contact_by_alternative_phone, :contact_by_Facebook, :contact_by_Twitter,  :contact_by_Instagram, 
                 :contact_by_LinkedIn,  :contact_by_other_social_media,  :contact_by_other_social_media_access)
```

end

def contact_preference_params  called from:

def update_cp

```
 @pid =  params[:items][:item][:participant_id]
 @item_id = params[:items][:contact_preference][:item_id]
 @current_item = nil

 if @item_id.nil?

   @current_item = ContactPreference.create!(contact_preference_params)

 else
   @cp = ContactPreference.where("participant_id = :pid and item_id = :iid", {pid: @pid, iid: @item_id }).first
   @current_item = @cp.update!(contact_preference_params)

 end 

 @current_item
```

end

Discovered I had an error in def, def update_cp

What worked is:

```
def contact_preference_params

params.require(:items).require(:contact_preference).permit(:item_id, :user_id, :use_which_contact_address,
                 :contact_by_chat, :contact_by_email, :contact_by_home_phone, :contact_by_cell_phone,  
                 :contact_by_alternative_phone, :contact_by_Facebook, :contact_by_Twitter,  :contact_by_Instagram, 
                 :contact_by_LinkedIn,  :contact_by_other_social_media,  :contact_by_other_social_media_access)
```

end

====== >> UPDATE

Discovered another problem;

ERROR: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'uploaded_picture' for ItemImage.):

Request param:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "commit"=>"new_item", 
"items"=>

{"item"=>{"field_changed"=>"1", "item_type"=>"lend", "remote_ip"=>"", "item_id"=>"", "participant_id"=>"", "category_id"=>"1", "other_item_category"=>"", "item_description"=>"ghfg", "item_condition_id"=>"3", "item_model"=>"fghgf", "item_count"=>"12", "notify"=>"0", "comment"=>"fgh gfhfg fghgf",

"item_images"=>{"item_image_id"=>"", "item_id"=>"", "uploaded_picture"=>#, @original_filename="foo.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"items[item][item_images][uploaded_picture]\"; filename=\"1[1].jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "item_image_caption"=>"foo"}}}, "id"=>""}

How does one access items => item => item_image => uploaded picture when uploaded_picture is an attr_acessor in model.rb

item_image.rb

```
class ItemImage < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :item

attr_accessor  :uploaded_picture, :item_type
before_save :uploaded_picture



private

 def uploaded_picture=(picture_field)

 unless (picture_field.blank?)

 begin

     name =  self.item_id.to_s + '_' + 
     File.basename(picture_field.original_filename).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')
     directory = './app/assets/images/'  +  self.item_type.to_s
     path = File.join(directory, name)
     # write the file -- b is for binary
     File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(picture_field.read) }
     self.image_file_name = name
     self.image_content_type = picture_field.content_type.chomp
     self.image_width = 0
     self.image_height = 0
    .... end
```

image_image table:

Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
item_image_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| 
item_id            | varchar(40)  | 
image_content_type | varchar(20)  | 
image_height       | int(3)       | 
image_width        | int(3)       | 
image_file_name    | varchar(150) | 
item_image_caption | varchar(50)  | 
...

html.erb

...
              <%= item_images.hidden_field :item_image_id %>

```
           <%= item_images.hidden_field :item_id %>

           <%= f.hidden_field :item_type, :value => @itype   %>

            <div style="margin-left:25px;margin-top:5px;float:left;">

              <%= item_images.label :uploaded_picture, "Image of Item" %> 

              <%= item_images.file_field :uploaded_picture %>

              <% if @ii %>

              <% if @ii.image_file_name %>

               <% @imageLibrary = @imageLibrary + "/" + @ii.image_file_name %>

             <% end %>
            <% end %>
             ...
```

ItemsController

```
def update_item

...
unless @current_item.nil?
@itemImageRecord = @current_item.item_images.update!(item_image_params)


else

@itemImageRecord = @current_item.item_images.create!(item_image_params)  

def item_image_params

params.require(:items).require(:item).permit(:item_images).permit(:item_id, :item_type, :item_image_caption, :uploaded_picture)

end
```

ERROR: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'uploaded_picture' for ItemImage.):

Comment: Please take your time to properly format your code.. Also, limit it to a bare minimum.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion.  Problem is that I haven't been able to use "Answer Your Question" so I've had only to edit my initial question. Otherwise, I have tried to honor the rule of four spaces before code.